# Trying to make phone number a link

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I'm trying to make a phone number clickable on a secondary menu in a theme !
The code from the theme is this:

```html
<?php if ( '' !== ( $et_phone_number = et_get_option( 'phone_number' ) ) ) : ?>
                    <span id="et-info-phone"><?php echo et_core_esc_previously( et_sanitize_html_input_text( $et_phone_number ) ); ?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

How can i make the phone number clickable ???

Comment: This is HTML 101.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<a href="tel:+18001234567">1 800 1234567</a>
```

in your code:

```
<?php if ( '' !== ( $et_phone_number = et_get_option( 'phone_number' ) ) ) : ?>
<span id="et-info-phone">
  <a href="tel:<?php echo et_core_esc_previously( et_sanitize_html_input_text( $et_phone_number ) ); ?>"><?php echo et_core_esc_previously( et_sanitize_html_input_text( $et_phone_number ) ); ?>
  </a>
</span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

the php `echo` within the `<a>` tag should make sure that the phone number does not contain spaces or other special characters, so that it is parsed properly in the browsers.

Comment: i know the html code....but how do i insert it in the code above ?

Comment: If you know the HTML code, you should know what `echo` does, and should be able to put `2+2` together :) Just make the effort...

Comment: Thank's for the efort Ron. I've tried the code you posted before i chosed to ask on the forum. It doesn't work.

Comment: What does not work? if your echoed php string is empty, that does not mean the HTML itself is not working. n here we are not troubleshooting the PHP code. Please clarify what exactly "doesn't work"

Answer (score -1):

In that section there are 2 boxes. One for the phone and the other for the email.
The code for the email is this:

```
                <a href="<?php echo esc_attr( 'mailto:' . $et_email ); ?>"><span id="et-info-email"><?php echo esc_html( $et_email ); ?></span></a>
```

An it works fine as a link for the email.